# Remove gridview top and bottom bar

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

Hy,
I want to remove this line from top and bottom of my grid view without setting the 
grid.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER); beacause i need it to scroll over.
[image: a busy cat]

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean because overscrolling is exactly what that blue shade is. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I just want to make the blue line invisible. I know that's the reason it appears but i don't know how to remove it or make it invisible without changing my functionality. I use the gridview in a vertical viewflipper and it's not so esthetical.

Comment: what other functionality? Isn't removing the blue line the only thing that grid.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER); does?

Comment: well if i set grid.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER); the gridview will not scroll over any more. Do you understand my dillema? I want to scroll over but not to have that line.

Comment: To understand better in a viewflipper i have a bumpy gridview and by bumpy i mean that if has reached the bottom or the top and i drag the gridview a little bit will have like an animation ok going up to the size of my drag and then will come back to it's original state. If i drag it harder it will go to my next page of my viewflipper. The thing is that blue line on the top and on the bottom is bothering me and i can't remove it.